# Why does Angular still add unknown selection?

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I am pretty new to Angular so I am missing something trivial:

```
<select ng-model="shop_index">
  <option ng-repeat="elem in shops" 
          ng-selected="{{$first}}" 
          ng-value="{{$index}}">{{elem.name}}</option>
</select>
```

When I look at created HTML code it looks fine except for that unknown entry. I add `ng-init="0"` to HTML code -- no change. I init the model value in controller (before fetching the data) -- no change. I init the model after fetching the data -- no change. This unknown option is simply welded :-).

I am not asking how to get rid of it (like adding it manually, but hidden) but how to fix the above code to remove it automatically.

Comment: Try to initiate `shop_index`.

Comment: It's because you aren't using `ngOptions`, nothing to do with `shop_index`.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH, as I wrote I already tried, in three placed at once, I see no other place where I can put init for it.

Comment: @DanPantry, ok, I will try, thank you, I was under impression the approach with `ng-value` is OK, quote from the doc "To bind the model to a non-string value, you can use one of the following strategies:" and using `ng-value` is one of three. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: @DanPantry, visually it works, but now on the other hand I have incorrect data in HTML. The options I use `ng-options="elem.name for elem in shops track by $index"`, the `value` attribute for all options is set `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

In your **controller**:

```
$scope.shop_index = $scope.shops[0];
```

In your **view**:

```
<select ng-model="shop_index" ng-options="elem as elem.name for elem in shops"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ngOptions` with select, otherwise the values will not be correctly linked up to the `select` until you select a value. The reason for this escapes me at the moment, but the basic idea is that the values you pass in will correspond to an array index rather than the values you may be used to.

The value of the input element as a result should be of no consequence to you.

The ngOptions directive should be in the form of `value as label for object in collection`.

If the values in the HTML are `undefined`, it's because the above expression is incorrect - make sure `value` points to a valid  value.

Comment: After using @developer033 code I also checked tracking by "elem.id" -- so it appears in case of arrays you cannot use tracking by index array, it has to be something that sits **inside** data (or the data itself -- like entire element).

Comment: you can definitely track by index in an array, but that's very likely *not* what you want because the value option in `ngOptions` is what `ngModel` is set to. You very likely don't want to have your model value be an index of an array.